# How to set the text of a ListBox in code-behind design

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a **System.Windows.Control.ListBox**, and I would like to select a specific index of it. For example, my listbox is red, white, and blue, and after I read an object/file, I want to select red as the window appears. What is the best way to do that?

```
public partial class MyWindow :  System.Windows.Window
     {
        public MyWindow()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             System.Windows.Control.ListBox MyListBox= (ListBox)this.FindName("myListBox");
         } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the **ListBox.SelectedIndex** property...

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    yourListBox.SelectedIndex = indexOfRed;
}
```